# matchFeatures does not match all features when comparing the same image. Why?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, feature-detection, surf

I have an image I (greyscale). I detected and extracted SURF features from this image :

```
poi = detectSURFFeatures(I);  
[features,validPoi] = extractFeatures(I,poi,'SURFSize',128);
```

373 features have been found. However, when I count the number of features matching to themselves, not all features match:

```
indexPairs = matchFeatures(features,features);
```

index pairs returns 365 matches only. Why ??? Note that I found this results for one image out of three only. For the other two images, matchFeatures returns the same number of features as extractFeatures. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The function `matchFeatures` has matching threshold parameters `MatchThreshold` and `MaxRation` which reject potentially false or ambiguous matches by for example stipulating that the best found match must be better than the second best match by a certain factor.

Even if the images are identical, this situation can arise.

Comment: Thanks! But does this influence the calculation of similarity between two images based on the number of matching features ? Currently, I am calculating it like this  : nbmatch = size(indexPairs,1); minsize = min(size(features,1)); similarity = nbmatch/minsize. This leads to a similarity measure for an image with itself that is lower than 1.

Comment: @Julien sure, because similarity in this formulation is a percentage of the matched features. And some matches, even from identical features, might still be rejected by the matching algorithm.

Comment: I thought this was the similarity mesurement proposed by Lowe in his paper presenting SIFT, but I should certainly re-read this paper... Thanks !

Comment: Yes, it is the measure proposed by Lowe.

Comment: So this measure of similarity should be good for object recognition but maybe not for my purpose: calculating a matrix of visual similarity between several images. In this case I need similarity measurements to be comparable between all images (thus the theoretical maximum value of similarity should be the same for all pairs of images). Which SIFT/SURF-based measure would you then recommend?

Comment: @Julien that is a different question, and probably one more suitable for research than so.

Comment: Very interesting - this problem is similar to something we're working on. @Julien have you been able to find SIFT/SURF-based measures that work?